# Android meaningful transitions example

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, material-design

How to implement this animation using curvedmotion because documentation does not have a good example.
https://www.google.com/design/spec/animation/meaningful-transitions.html#meaningful-transitions-hierarchical-timing

[image: Consistent choreography]

Comment: [Check](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/material/animations.html#CurvedMotion). Its right there at the bottom of the documentation you mention.

Comment: Also, Topeka https://github.com/googlesamples/android-topeka/releases/tag/09072015

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, the path is basically a quarter of an oval. The parametric equation of an oval is like this:

```
x = a * cos(t)
y = b * cos(t)
```

See http://www.mathopenref.com/coordparamellipse.html

You have three parameters. Two of them (a, b) are the width and the height of the bounding box of your quarter-oval. The third one can be taken from animation interpolator. To get the right quarter, you need a value from range `[PI*3/2, PI*2]`.

```
final View fab;
final int startX = fab.getTranslationX(),startY = fab.getTranslationY();
final int endX = 100,endY = 0;
ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat((float)(Math.PI*3/2),(float)(Math.PI*2));
animator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
animator.setDuration(500);
animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
        float t = (float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
        float a = endX-startX;
        float b = endY-startY;
        fab.setTranslationX((float) (a*Math.cos(t)));
        fab.setTranslationY((float) (b*Math.sin(t)));
    }
});
animator.start();
```